# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'size' in kivy environment

Tags: python

[enter image description here][1]![ho][2]

i am trying to run kivymd collection example in my system and currently i am using Windows i beginner so please help me out if any one know to solve the this problem it would very helpful for me thank in advance

```
class Container(Widget):
    def __init__(self, source, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.bind(size=self.adjust_size, pos=self.adjust_size)
        self.image = Image(source=source)

    def adjust_size(self, *args):
        (par_x, par_y) = self.parent.size

        if par_x == 0 or par_y == 0:
            with self.canvas:
                self.canvas.clear()
            return

        par_scale = par_x / par_y

       (img_x, img_y) = self.image.texture.size
       img_scale = img_x / img_y

       if par_scale > img_scale:
           (img_x_new, img_y_new) = (img_x, img_x / par_scale)
       else:
           (img_x_new, img_y_new) = (img_y * par_scale, img_y)

       crop_pos_x = (img_x - img_x_new) / 4
       crop_pos_y = (img_y - img_y_new) / 4

       subtexture = self.image.texture.get_region(
           crop_pos_x, crop_pos_y, img_x_new, img_y_new
       )

       with self.canvas:
           self.canvas.clear()
           Color(1, 1, 1)
           Rectangle(texture=subtexture, pos=self.pos, size=(par_x, par_y))
```

Comment: Post your code.

Comment: Use a debugger to find out why `self.image.texture` is `None`

Comment: error in (img_x, img_y) = self.image.texture.size
       img_scale = img_x / img_y

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for responding me problem get solved.
i did adding kivy path in environment variable
and i installed kivymd version 1.104.1

1. pip install kivymd==0.104.1
2. pip install https://github.com/kivymd/KivyMD/archive/master.zip

it working fine now all i want do this add to library and set a path.
my suggestion is like virtual environment create module environment for essay import library's and not need to add path it will be more eassy